# Separating a column element into 3 separate columns (R)

Tags: r

I have a data frame (theData) as follows which has values separated by pipes:

```
Col1  Col2     Col3 
1     colors   red|green|purple
1     colors   red|pink|yellow
1     colors   yellow|mauve|purple
1     colors   red|green|orange
1     colors   red|yellow|purple
1     colors   red|green|purple
```

I would like to separate the Col3 into additional columns like this:

```
Col1     Col2        Col3                    Col4      Col5  
1       colors      red                     green     purple
1       colors      red                     pink      yellow
1       colors      yellow                  mauve     purple
1       colors      red                     green     orange
1       colors      red                     yellow    purple
1       colors      red                     green     purple
```

I have tried the following:

```
str_split_fixed(as.character(theData$Col3), "|", 3)
```

but this does not work.

Comment: Maybe something like `cbind(theData[, c(1,2 )], as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(theData$Col3, "|", fixed=T))))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try `colsplit` from `reshape`

```
  library(reshape)
  cbind(theData[,1:2],
     colsplit(theData$Col3, "[|]", names=c("Col3", "Col4", "Col5")))
  #  Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5
 #1    1 colors    red  green purple
 #2    1 colors    red   pink yellow
 #3    1 colors yellow  mauve purple
 #4    1 colors    red  green orange
 #5    1 colors    red yellow purple
 #6    1 colors    red  green purple
```

Or  just use `read.table`

```
   cbind(theData[,1:2],
         setNames(read.table(text=theData$Col3,sep="|",header=F,stringsAsFactors=F),paste0("Col",3:5)))
```

Answer (score 2):

[My `cSplit` function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733/) handles this type of problem quite easily.

```
cSplit(theData, "Col3", "|")
#    Col1   Col2 Col3_1 Col3_2 Col3_3
# 1:    1 colors    red  green purple
# 2:    1 colors    red   pink yellow
# 3:    1 colors yellow  mauve purple
# 4:    1 colors    red  green orange
# 5:    1 colors    red yellow purple
# 6:    1 colors    red  green purple
```

The result is a `data.table` since the function makes use of the "data.table" package for the efficiencies it offers, particularly with larger datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Add one more option. See if you like. It's Hadley's tidyr package. The code is quite clean.

```
> library(tidyr)
> test <- data.frame(Col3 = c("red|green|purple", "red|pink|yellow"))
> test
Source: local data frame [2 x 1]

              Col3
1 red|green|purple
2  red|pink|yellow

> test %>% separate(Col3, c("A", "B", "C"), sep = "\\|")
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]

    A     B      C
1 red green purple
2 red  pink yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to wrap `|` with `[]`, or escape it with `\\|`.  This looks like a job for `mapply`.

```
> m <- mapply(strsplit, dat$Col3, split = "[|]", USE.NAMES = FALSE)
> setNames(cbind(dat[-3], do.call(rbind, m)), paste0("Col", 1:5))
#   Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5
# 1    1 colors    red  green purple
# 2    1 colors    red   pink yellow
# 3    1 colors yellow  mauve purple
# 4    1 colors    red  green orange
# 5    1 colors    red yellow purple
# 6    1 colors    red  green purple
```

Using your attempt with `str_split_fixed`, it would just need a little change,

```
> library(stringr)
> cbind(dat[-3], str_split_fixed(dat$Col3, "[|]", 3))
```